# why dont I get the latest output?

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, itext, netbeans6.8

I am using Netbeans IDE 6.8 to run my web application in Glassfish v2.

I am using iText to develop pdf.

Each time I make an change in the program its not reflected in the output.

What might be the reason?

Comment: maybe you always run the same code. clean+build and run again

Comment: @hilal so do you say I should clean and build each time I make a small change.I already have the auto-compile option on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what program and what kind of change you are talking about. I shall assume that it is the changes in webapp because I have similar problem.

I am using Netbeans to develop my web application and deploy it to tomcat for testing. Netbeans does not reload the changes I make to the class files automatically. I need to rerun (no need for clean and build) them whole web application project everything I make a small change. However, it seems to be able to detect the changes if the web.xml is modified.

I am not aware that Netbeans can auto detect and redeploy webapp likes Eclipse. Eclipse can automatically redeploy your webapp if there are changes, which makes it very convenient to develop a webapp. However, Netbeans is still my best IDE.

There is a commercial plugin, [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/), which allows Netbeans (and other IDEs) and your servlet containers to reload just the modified class automatically without having to redeploy the whole application, making web development even more faster.

These are merely my own experience and I will be very greatful if someone has other tips for automatic webapp redeployment in Netbeans.